# Wordpress user pagination issue

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have the following code which isn't displaying the pagination links no matter what number of users I request to be displayed.

Not sure how to get the pagination to work - any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
<?php   

$number     = 10;  
$paged      = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
$offset     = ($paged - 1) * $number;  
$users      = get_users($args);  
$query      = get_users('role=Recruiter&offset='.$offset.'&number='.$number);  
$total_users = count($users);  
$total_query = count($query);  
$total_pages = intval($total_users / $number) + 1;  

var_dump($query);

echo '<ul id="users">';  

foreach($query as $q) { ?>  

<li class="user clearfix">  
    <div class="user-avatar">  
        <?php echo get_avatar( $q->ID, 80 ); ?>      
    </div>  
    <div class="user-data">  

        <h4 class="user-name">  
            <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($q->ID);?>">  
                <?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $q->ID);?>  
            </a>  
        </h4>  

        <?php if (get_the_author_meta('description', $q->ID) != '') : ?>  
            <p><?php echo get_the_author_meta('description', $q->ID); ?></p>  
        <?php endif; ?>  

    </div>  
</li>  

<?php }   

echo '</ul>';  

?>  

<?php  
if ($total_users > $total_query) {  
echo '<div id="pagination" class="clearfix">';  
echo '<span class="pages">Pages:</span>';  
  $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));  
  echo paginate_links(array(  
    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',  
    'format' => 'page/%#%/',  
    'current' => $current_page,  
    'total' => $total_pages,  
    'prev_next'    => false,  
    'type'         => 'list',  
));  
echo '</div>';  
?>
```

Comment: Why do you need `$users = get_users($args);`?

Comment: I suppose I could just set $total_users to $number. It sets up the if statement for pagination.

Comment: Assuming `$args` are the same as `'role=Recruiter&offset='.$offset.'&number='.$number`, `$total_users` and `$total_query` will hold the same value

Comment: Thanks for the input - found a solution [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18639/modifying-wp-list-author-functions-to-output-all-users-in-a-grid-and-paginate) and modified it.